# Initializing an array outside class after declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

For example:

```
const int m = 10;
class C{
public:
   double A[m];
};
int main(){
    C name;
    name.A[m] = ...  // initializing here?
}
```

I can't find a way around that, I could for example do

```
C name = {...};
```

Which would perfectly work but for the sake of functionality I wanna know if I can do that for single variables inside the class.

Comment: There's no other way than a loop.

Comment: in the 2nd line of main. you are not initializing anymore.

Comment: `name.A[m] = <something>` will invoke UB

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you only need to write:

```
   name.A[x]=value;
```

Where `value` is `double` and `x` is between 0 and 9. You can also make a loop if you wish to set values for all or some of its elements.